# How to specify Future type correctly

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm trying to figure out how to specify types in code like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() async {
  Map repos = await(fetchJson());
  print(repos['name']);
}

Object fetchJson() async {
  final uri = 'https://api.github.com/users/sjindel-google/repos';
  final response = await http.get(uri);
  return jsonDecode(response.body)[1];
}
```

That code works, but I want to specify the type for fetchJson(). It seems like it should be:

```
Future<Map> fetchJson() async {
```

But that gives me the runtime error:

```
Error: 'Future' expects 0 type arguments.
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Never mind. I forgot to import 'dart:async'. 

Not a helpful error message.

Comment: Soon importing `dart:async` for `Future` or `Stream` won't be necessary anymore.

Comment: That's great, thanks Gunter.